# Tricky trigonometry question (distance of a ship)

Tags: trigonometry

A telescope, that is to be used to view ships out at sea, is placed at the top  of a cliff that is **150 m high.**

Using suitable diagrams, show how the distance of the ship from the shore could be calculated using the angle at which the telescope is tilted in order to get the ship in its sights.
Set out an examplar calculation using a realistic angle of your choice.

Comment: Is the earth flat? Also is the tilt from vertical or horizontal.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardon my paint skills but I think you have it like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq3Av.png (the triangle is right in O)

Basically you need to compute the distance OB, which can be given by the following formula :

$$\tan(\alpha) = OB/OT$$

Then,

$$OB = tan(\alpha)\cdot OT$$

If you know the angle $\alpha$ you already know the distance OT which is 150m, so you know the distance from the ship to the shore

A "realistic" angle could be 73.3° so the ship is 500m from the shore

Comment: Don't you think you should take the curvature of the earth into consideration?

Comment: @5xum umm 6400km radius, 150m high telescope. isn't curvature overkill?

Comment: I believe it's negligible ? Otherwise I didn't think of it at all

Comment: Without taking the curvature of the earth into consideration, the result would be 99.9999% accurate (probably) anyway. Good enough I would presume.

Comment: @MitchKnight You are slightly off. I've calculated 99.98689%.

Comment: Haha my apologies.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Proof or it didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.    Consider a circle of radius $r$; the telescope's height is $h$ and let $\alpha$ be the tilt angle. So $r+h$ is the telescope's distance from the center. Let $\beta$ be the angle between the telescope, the center and ship's position.  From here 
$$\frac{\sin(180-\alpha-\beta)}{r+h}=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{r}.$$
For $\alpha=73.3$ we have $\beta=0.0045119$, thus the spherical distance is --assuming $r=6350000$ meters -- 500.041 meters instead of 499.494. For $\alpha=89$ we get 8955.27 instead of 8593.49.